# where can I put an image file so the program can automatically find it?

Tags: c#, image

currently I am trying to make it so that I can get access to the image "staticmap.bmp" from within the program so that I can then transfer the program to another computer and still have access to the image. I have tried transferring the file into the program file, but it does not show in the visual studio tab as being there, perhaps I am moving it to the wrong place?. Either that or I am calling it in correctly?

Does anyone know where a picture file has to be for it to be called?

Here is the code,

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("staticmap.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it as an embedded resource into the application. A simple Google search will find a tutorial for doing this.

Comment: I added the image as a resources, how do I call it?

Comment: In C# you would use Properties.Resources.<Resource Name>

In VB you would use My.Resources.<Resource Name>

Comment: Thanks for this, now I know how to do an Embedded Resource!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to open the file like this:

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("staticmap.bmp");
```

Then staticmap.bmp simply needs to be in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: But the better solution is to add it as a resource (as the other comments suggest). This way it is embedded in the .exe and you don't have to manage it separately from the .exe.

Comment: It is in the same folder as the executable but it still cannot find it :(

Comment: Are you running the .exe from VS.NET?

Comment: Ah running it from the application makes it show up but now I am getting the error, An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Comment: When you specify a file name without directory then the current directory will be used. This is not necessarily the application directory. Often this is the last directory that was accessed in an open file dialog.

Comment: Put the .exe and the .bmp into a directory. Open a command prompt. Go to that directory. Run your app. Does it work?

Comment: Or better yet, go the resource route because then you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I think Olivier is likely right as I am calling from other areas aswell so i have decided to do an embedded resource

Answer (score 1):

Right click on image in solution explorer, choose "Properties". Set "Build action" to "Content" and "Copy to output directory" to "Copy always" to ensure that image is copied to the same directory as executable on build.

Or, right click on project in solution explorer, choose "Properties", go to "Resources" tab, press small arrow at the right side of "Add resource" button, choose "Add existing file" and select image to use as resource. Then you may use it like this:

```
Image image = Properties.Resources.staticmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a resource - right click project, properties, resources.

see [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

An application can determine from which directory it has been started like this

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath
);
```

An alternative is (if you don't have a reference to WinForms):

```
string dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
);
```

If the image resides in a subdirectory `Images` located in your application directory

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, @"Images\staticmap.bmp"));
```